# Post json body sending email to only first recipient Address

Tags: json, linux, curl

I have file body.json file -

```
{"recipientAddress":"abc@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}}
{"recipientAddress":"xyz@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}}
{"recipientAddress":"def@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}}
```

Now, when I am running -

```
curl -X POST "https://api.com/messaging/message/email"-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @body.json
```

it sending and email to only first email address i.e. abc@gmail.com

Can someone help me as email should trigger to all 3 recipient Address?

Thanks,

Comment: did you try removing the line breaks in the JSON file?  also, if you send it like that it isnt valid as full JSON - you are basically sending an "array" of three objects there but you don't have an array wrapping it so it's probably taking the first correct data and disregarding the rest.  try wrapping it all in `[]` first

Comment: to be more specific:  `[{"recipientAddress":"abc@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}},
{"recipientAddress":"xyz@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}},
{"recipientAddress":"def@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}}]`

Comment: may be easier to see in an answer, even if you somehow have a different issue than I'm reading into here.  See below in a second

Answer (score 0):

Combined with the comments above, try the following and re-submit:

```
[
    {"recipientAddress":"abc@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}},

    {"recipientAddress":"xyz@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}},

    {"recipientAddress":"def@gmail.com","staticMessage":{"senderAddress":"noreply@mail.co.uk","subject":"Report","body":"Unique Users LoggedIn on 14/12/2019 - 7"}}
];
```

---

Also it is worth mentioning this also depends on this particular API you are using.  So first thing you should try is consult the API docs.  A `POST` request isnt a hard-fast rule so for all we know this means "give us ONE item at a time".